# Airplane mode switch disables Wi-Fi+Bluetooth but re-enables only Bluetooth

Tags: windows-8, lenovo-laptop, wireless-adapter, airplane-mode

In my Lenovo Yoga 13 (Windows 8.0), when I set airplane mode switch:

- switched **on**

  ```
   Bluetooth: disabled
       Wi-Fi: disabled
  ```
- switched **off**

  ```
   Bluetooth: re-enabled
       Wi-Fi: no effect (remains disabled)
  ```

So I always need to go re-enable Wi-Fi manually in Wireless settings.

**Is there any way to make Airplane mode switch re-enable also the Wi-Fi adapter?**

It looks it could be a [problem with ACPI interface](http://billauer.co.il/blog/2014/08/linux-ubuntu-yoga-hardware-blocked-wireless-lan/).

Comment: sounds like a setting you'd have to set in the registry. may want to do some googles including registry in your search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this problem with a lot of Yoga devices in the Lenovo forum.

Here is a list of possible solution you could try which I found there:

1. Update Wireless and Wireless button driver (from Lenovo only).
2. If this problem was not there before, then see if resetting PC works.
3. If there's really a hardware lock then see if updating BIOS works.
4. Contact Lenovo for support.